# Will connecting unused CMOS outputs to VCC damage the chip?

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cmos

I am using a 74HC154 4x16 decoder in a design I'm working on and I'm not using the last four outputs. During PCB routing it would be very convenient if I could tie these unused outputs to the VCC flood. Would this cause a short circuit when those outputs are low?

Comment: Yes. Yes it would.

Comment: Cosimos Cendo - Hi, Why do you believe that you need to connect unused CMOS *outputs* to anything? This might be an XY-problem...

Comment: With CMOS you don't want floating inputs, unused outputs should be left unconnected unless there is a specific reason otherwise.

Comment: If and when the output goes low, the chip may overhear, the consumption will increase and the failure rate will increase. Leave unused output not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chip damage is not guaranteed, but is possible.
It will cause a short circuit when those outputs drive low.

Comment: It will most probably exceed absolute maximum ratings for current and power quite quickly. And it will draw a lot of power and generate heat in the part.